# Iterate outwards from a starting point in a volume or area without sorting it

Tags: c++, loops, graph-algorithm

Let's say I have a 4x3 linear array of integers stored in row-major order. The layout (indexes) are shown below. Let's say the value at each index is the same as the index.

```
00 01 02 03
04 05 06 07
08 09 10 11
```

I can loop through this array as follows:

```
for(int y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
   for(int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
       std::cout << array[y*4+x] << ",";
```

I would get

```
00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,
```

And, of course, I can loop in a slightly different way:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
   for(int y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
       std::cout << array[y*4+x] << ",";
```

And get

```
00,04,08,01,05,09,02,06,10,03,07,11,
```

But is there a way, without first sorting the array, to loop through it getting the following (or similar) result:

```
05,04,01,06,09,00,02,10,08,07,03,11
```

That is, to start at some specified location `[x=1,y=1]` and iterate outwards in (sort of) a spiral, that is sorted by distance.

```
05 02 06 10
01 00 03 09
08 04 07 11
```

I know I can achieve that by first sorting the array by some predicate that returns the distance from `[x=1,y=1]`, but (for performance) is it possible to do without first sorting?

---

**Edit:**

To elaborate, I just want to start at point `[x=1,y=1]` and iterate as if the points had been sorted via Manhatten (`|x1-x2| + |y1-y2|`) or even Euclidean (`sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)`).

Here's a larger array. It doesn't have to be exactly like this, since it can satisfy the sort, with a different output (for example, it could be CCW rather than CW).

```
05 01 06 11 17
04 00 02 09 15
08 03 07 14 18
13 10 12 16 19
```

Comment: Please provide a bigger array to explain how this spiral is to work.  But the terse answer to your question is “yes”.

Comment: Sit down with a pen and paper; work out the equation of x and y in the array that you want to access for a given step; and then go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Make a sequence of offsets in the correct order for a spiral, long enough for any starting position. Either as a static table, or as a generating function.

Loop through that offset sequence, adding each to the starting co-ordinate. Skip any out of bounds co-ordinates. Stop when you have found `width * height` valid co-ordinates

Answer (score 1):

With Manhattan distance, you might use something like:

```
visit(center);
for (int distance = 1; distance != max_distance; ++distance) {
    for (int i = 0; i != distance; ++i) {
        visit(center - {-distance + i, i});
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != distance; ++i) {
        visit(center - {i, distance - i});
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != distance; ++i) {
        visit(center - {distance - i, -i});
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != distance; ++i) {
        visit(center - {-i, -distance + i});
    }
}
```

You might add bound checking in `visit`, or adjust each boundary (You will have to split each inner loop).